# Why am I getting an error when attempting to convert an MP4 video to RealMedia video with FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

FFmpeg failed to transcode `test1.mp4`. Below are the reported errors.

I want to convert my video to RealMedia, so what is good preset for my goal?

```
[rm @ 0x55795eac0340] Muxing packets larger than 64 kB (80556) is not supported
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Not yet implemented in FFmpeg, patches welcome
```

Executed commands and output

```
ffmpeg -i test1.mp4 -threads 1 -c:v rv10 -vf "scale=1280:720" -c:a ac3 test1.rm -y
ffmpeg version 4.3.4-0+deb11u1 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10 (Debian 10.2.1-6)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0+deb11u1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-libmfx --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'test1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41
    creation_time   : 2018-02-13T23:22:01.000000Z
  Duration: 00:03:48.74, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 10030 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 2560x1440, 9708 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 60k tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-02-13T23:22:01.000000Z
      handler_name    : ?Mainconcept Video Media Handler
      encoder         : AVC Coding
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 317 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-02-13T23:22:01.000000Z
      handler_name    : #Mainconcept MP4 Sound Media Handler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> rv10 (native))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> ac3 (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, rm, to 'test1.rm':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: rv10 (RV10 / 0x30315652), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x720, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-02-13T23:22:01.000000Z
      handler_name    : ?Mainconcept Video Media Handler
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 rv10
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: ac3 (dnet / 0x74656E64), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-02-13T23:22:01.000000Z
      handler_name    : #Mainconcept MP4 Sound Media Handler
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 ac3
[rm @ 0x55795eac0340] Muxing packets larger than 64 kB (80556) is not supported
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Not yet implemented in FFmpeg, patches welcome
frame=    5 fps=0.0 q=4.7 Lsize=      79kB time=00:00:00.08 bitrate=7765.9kbits/s speed=1.12x    
video:156kB audio:2kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
Conversion failed!
```

Comment: Why do you want to convert to such an outdated format?

Comment: Look at this [Reddit discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/ffmpeg/comments/ce6874/convert_mp4_to_realvideo_rm_rmvb_rv_etc/) and see if it helps.